# Webfilter Java RequestDispatcher affords content of site in the debugger console not a redirecting to

Tags: java

I have a JQUERY call to a servlet. Before the servelt is call, i want to use a filter to check if a user is succeffully signed in:

```
$.get("Anwender",function(data){

    console.log(data);


    $.each(data,function(key,value){
     [...]
    }

 [...]
}
```

My Filter to check if the user is logged in looks like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String jwt = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

if (jwt != null) {
//Some stuff here

 }
else
 {
final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("fehler.html");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);

 }
}
```

So if i tries to run the code the else statement is called, but in my debug console i see the content of the fehler.html. Just in the console not at the webbroswer.

[image]

And all JS,CSS files are also loaded. 
So why i can't see the right html site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if:

1. your JQuery code makes an AJAX call to your webserver
2. your server returns an html response
3. The browser receives the **text html response** in variable *data*
4. The browser logs HTML

So client and Server don't match. The Server wants to do "normal HTTP" and redirect a client that's not authenticated. The clients wants to call a *Rest Service* or something similar and handle the response.

If I were you, I'd change the Server response to an Error with a Status Code 4xx and have the client handle it.